# After create or concat dynamic string how its execute and got data in place or data row filed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I will do work with asp.net C#. when I create runtime string (dynamic). After the string, I try to pass the data in the place of data row but I have no idea about that so please provide a proper solution.
**Below is my code (code with example )**

```
protected string Replace_Tag(string Email_msg)
{
    try {

        }
       return  Email_msg ;
}
```

After execute this function result found below. (return below string)

> "View your all the details"  + drmail["WorkName"].ToString() + 
>   "this task is working " + drmail["Cjworkmode"].ToString() +  "- " +
>   drmail["Cjtimeperiod"].ToString() + " 
> "

This is the string so how can I execute this string in for loop and get the proper data.

**For loop**

```
string cast_data = Replace_Tag(EditorEmail.Content);
    foreach (DataRow drmail in Get_Tab_Data().Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        String Vie_Data = cast_data;
    }
```

**In this for loop how to get below result.**

- View your all the details XYZ this task is working ABC - 2018
- View your all the details ABC this task is working ABC - 2019
- View your all the details EFG this task is working MZP - 2017

Answer (score 0):

This is a principle called "string templating". Do some research to find existing solutions. If you don't want to use existing solutions, roll your own.

You could do so by introducing placeholders in the template string:

```
var templateString = "View all the details {WorkName} this task is working {Cjworkmode} - {Cjtimeperiod}";
```

Not to be confused with string interpolation, as these placeholders aren't known at compile time.

Then, for example using a regular expression, find all matches in the string:

```
var placeHolderRegEx = new Regex(@"(\{([a-z]+)\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Copy the string to be templated  
var output = templateString;

foreach (Match match in placeHolderRegEx.Matches(templateString))
{
    // Replace each instance of `{x}` with the value of `drmail[x]`.
    output = output.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, drmail[match.Groups[2].Value]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my example, I give a string is already do match replace code. after replacement, I found this string. in given string i try to bound SQL database data "Workname, cjworkmode " this is the database field. In for loop, I use SQL database data so I try to dynamic data binding.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by that. You can't execute code from a string like `drmail["WorkName"].ToString()` in `""View your all the details" + drmail["WorkName"].ToString()"`". You need to do the replacement manually, and placeholders can help there.